# Automatically spawning children with simple_one_to_one

Tags: erlang

When using `simple_one_to_one` in a supervisor, the children haven't started automatically.  By the examples, I should run `supervisor:start_child(chat_liason_sup, DataForChild).` to start a child.  In the real world, we want to execute the erlang application, and not sit at the console to start a child.  How can I get at least one child to start automatically?  One trick I considered was to have a normal `one_for_one` started at the same time, which would, in turn, start the `simple_one_for_one` children.  But it looks like I can only start one kind of child in a given supervisor...

Answer (score 1):

I use the simple_one_for_one strategy when I need a process factory. Generally, I have a first supervisor using a one_for_one or one_for_all strategy, and whose children are

- a server responsible for a part of the application, and whose job includes the start of multiple and identical processes
- the simple_one_for_one supervisor.

Doing this I take advantage of the OTP to manage the life cycle of all the processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start more than one kind of child, do not use `simple_one_for_one`. `supervisor:start_child/2` accepts `child_spec()` for other types of supervisor. If you want to start child automatically, use another process and more than one supervisor. One way is to use one supervisor for a launcher and second `simple_one_for_one` supervisor for children. But you can use as many supervisors as you want.